# Laravel 5 - Extending a Abstract Provider

Tags: php, abstract-class, laravel-5, service-provider, extending-classes

I am trying to extend  **Laravel\Socialite\Two\AbstractProvider** , and I am unsure what is the best / proper way to do this in Laravel. Reading the documentation has lead me to believe I should be doing this in a service provider.

Any help would be great, here is the code that I have for my service provider:

*SocialiteServiceProvider.php*

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class SocialiteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider  {

    public function register()
    {
        \App::bind('socialize', function()
        {
            echo 'DOESN\'T GET HERE';
            // what do i put here once I do get here
        });
    }
}
```

Then I have a second file

*SocialiteAbstractProvider.php*

```
<?php namespace App\Services;

use Laravel\Socialite\Two\AbstractProvider;

abstract class SocialiteAbstractProvider extends AbstractProvider
{
    /**
     * Get the authentication URL for the provider.
     *
     * @param  string  $state
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getAuthUrl($state);


    /**
     * Get the token URL for the provider.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getTokenUrl();

    /**
     * Get the raw user for the given access token.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getUserByToken($token);

    /**
     * Map the raw user array to a Socialite User instance.
     *
     * @param  array  $user
     * @return \Laravel\Socialite\User
     */
    protected function mapUserToObject(array $user);

    public function redirect()
    {
        echo '@s1';
        die;
        $this->request->getSession()->set(
            'state', $state = http_build_query(
                array(
                    'token' => sha1(time().$this->request->getSession()->get('_token')),
                    'domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
                )
            )
        );

        return new RedirectResponse($this->getAuthUrl($state));
    }
}
```

I also have properly added it to my config as I am able to see the register event.

Comment: Just that part: `return new AbstractProvider();` looks plain wrong to me... You can't instantiate an abstract class

Comment: You are correct, I believe I am on a diff path now , going to edit and see if it makes more sense/

Comment: I've updated it, but im still unsure what im really suppose todo.

Comment: It seems to be an ongoing matter even in laravel forums there is no thread with a solution regarding to this matter :( it might be something that came with 5.2

Comment: no, this was 5.1 , this has been here for a very long time.